# python numpy how to insert multiple rows between each row

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a numpy array like this:

- 26.4812 32.0000 -5.0000 10000.0000 20000.0000 2.0000
- 26.4812 32.0000 10.0000 10000.0000 20000.0000 2.0000
- 26.4812 32.0000 0.0000 10000.0000 20000.0000 2.0000...

I want to change it so that the 3rd column(z value) has more steps like this:

- 26.4812 32.0000 -5.0000 10000.0000 20000.0000 2.0000
- 26.4812 32.0000 -4.0000 10000.0000 20000.0000 2.0000
- 26.4812 32.0000 -3.0000 10000.0000 20000.0000 2.0000
- ...
- 26.4812 32.0000 9.0000 10000.0000 20000.0000 2.0000
- 26.4812 32.0000 10.0000 10000.0000 20000.0000 2.0000...

the steps must be defined by a variable step = 1mm at this example.
how can i achive that?

Comment: please provide a **minimal** and **reproducible** example (both words are important)

Comment: Did you try a simple `for` loop to generate a list then convert it to numpy array ? Otherwise you can try to split the array to insert elements or generate a bigger array and replace the z values.

Answer (score 0):

This is little ugly maybe but it does what you want:

```
arr1 = np.array([[1, -3, -3],
           [1, 3, 3],
           [1, 3, 7]])
z=arr1[:, 2]
new_z = []
for i in range(len(z)-1):
     new_z.append(np.arange(z[i],z[i+1]+1))
new_z = np.unique(np.concatenate(new_z))
new_array = np.c_[np.repeat(arr1[0, 0], new_z.shape[0]), new_z, 
np.repeat(arr1[0, 2], new_z.shape[0])]
print(new_array)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import numpy as np

def generate_array(zmin, zmax, step=1):
  # generate z values based on min, max and step (-5, 10, and 1 in the example)
  z_values= np.arange(zmin, zmax+step, step)

  # create an array with the same data for every z value (for now)
  default_value = 0
  array = np.repeat([[26.4812, 32.0000, default_value, 10000.0000, 20000.0000, 2.0000]], len(z_values), axis=0)
  
  # replace the z values
  array[:, 2] = z_values

  return array
```

This can be used like this

```py
>>> generate_array(-5, 10)
>>> array([
  [ 2.64812e+01,  3.20000e+01, -5.00000e+00,  1.00000e+04, 2.00000e+04,  2.00000e+00],
  [ 2.64812e+01,  3.20000e+01, -4.00000e+00,  1.00000e+04, 2.00000e+04,  2.00000e+00],
  [ 2.64812e+01,  3.20000e+01, -3.00000e+00,  1.00000e+04, 2.00000e+04,  2.00000e+00],
  [ 2.64812e+01,  3.20000e+01, -2.00000e+00,  1.00000e+04, 2.00000e+04,  2.00000e+00],
  [ 2.64812e+01,  3.20000e+01, -1.00000e+00,  1.00000e+04, 2.00000e+04,  2.00000e+00],
  [ 2.64812e+01,  3.20000e+01,  0.00000e+00,  1.00000e+04, 2.00000e+04,  2.00000e+00],
  [ 2.64812e+01,  3.20000e+01,  1.00000e+00,  1.00000e+04, 2.00000e+04,  2.00000e+00],
  [ 2.64812e+01,  3.20000e+01,  2.00000e+00,  1.00000e+04, 2.00000e+04,  2.00000e+00],
  [ 2.64812e+01,  3.20000e+01,  3.00000e+00,  1.00000e+04, 2.00000e+04,  2.00000e+00],
  [ 2.64812e+01,  3.20000e+01,  4.00000e+00,  1.00000e+04, 2.00000e+04,  2.00000e+00],
  [ 2.64812e+01,  3.20000e+01,  5.00000e+00,  1.00000e+04, 2.00000e+04,  2.00000e+00],
  [ 2.64812e+01,  3.20000e+01,  6.00000e+00,  1.00000e+04, 2.00000e+04,  2.00000e+00],
  [ 2.64812e+01,  3.20000e+01,  7.00000e+00,  1.00000e+04, 2.00000e+04,  2.00000e+00],
  [ 2.64812e+01,  3.20000e+01,  8.00000e+00,  1.00000e+04, 2.00000e+04,  2.00000e+00],
  [ 2.64812e+01,  3.20000e+01,  9.00000e+00,  1.00000e+04, 2.00000e+04,  2.00000e+00],
  [ 2.64812e+01,  3.20000e+01,  1.00000e+01,  1.00000e+04, 2.00000e+04,  2.00000e+00]
])
```

Comment: but the Z value changes multiple times, for example -5 to 10 to 0 to 30 ... and so on.

Comment: That fact wasn't made clear in your question. You could apply my answer multiple times if you can identify what are the various Z values. Possibly, look at [pandas groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html). If that doesn't answer the question, you should open another question but explain everything.